# Error no me corre mi aplicacion en android studio

Tags: android, gradle

Estoy estudiando **Android** básico y cuando intento correr mi aplicación me sale este error.

> Error runnig app: Gradle project sync failed,please fix your project
>   and try again

Nota :tengo  el jdk de java 7

y estoy en windows 8

Comment: Tienes conexión a internet en el PC?, porque entiendo que intenta sincronizar y bajar dependencias, la otra es en el menu configuración gradle, marca la casilla wrapper default y prueba

Comment: Adicionalmente, si estas utilizando Android Studio y si haces clic en donde dice 0:Messages hay mas info en el mensaje de error?

Comment: Amigo @Sommer, tienes que dar más datos en tus preguntas, las respuestas pueden ser multiples, considero tu respuesta como demasiado amplia =(

Answer (score 1):

Está muy abierta esa pregunta, puede ser cualquier cosa, lo que me queda decirte es que abras el SDK manager y actualices/descargues todos los packages existentes y faltantes, reinicies Android Studio y vuelvas a compilar tu proyecto.

Si no se resuelve puedes intentar usar la última versión del Gradle:

- Ve a su página oficial y descarga [la última versión](http://services.gradle.org/distributions).
- Una vez descargada la extraes en el lugar que gustes, por ejemplo *C://Android/Gradle*.
- Abre tu proyecto en Android Studio y ve hacia *File->Settings->Gradle*.
- Seleccionas *Use local Gradle distribution* y elige la carpeta donde está ubicado el Gradle que descomprimiste y reinicias tu proyecto.

¡Éxito! :D